# Does being Nonempty Compact Set on $\mathbb{R^+_2}$ imply being Convex set?

Tags: general-topology, analysis, convex-analysis, compactness

Look at the domain of a function $y=x-2$ where $x\in\mathbb{R_+}$.

 Then, the triangle produced by x and y-intercepts is bounded and closed. So it is compact. Suppose it is also nonempty.

 Does this imply the set is convex? 

Graphically, the answer is YES. And using the definition of a set being convex, YES (e.g. for any $\alpha\in[0,1]$...).

 But my question is can we make a direct implication between compact set and convex set?

 Thanks!

Comment: If $x\in \mathbb R^2,$ what sense does $x-2$ make?

Comment: @zhw, a nonsense. well I call it Monday nonsense. you?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, of course not. Any finite set with more than one point is compact and not convex.

Comment: Hi T, thanks for the answer. Can you give me a blatant example to shed some more light? I am keep thinking of the triangle that is created under the line say, $y=2-x$, and see that it is closed and bounded triangle... So from your answer, I thought of a set $S=\{1,5\}$. This is compact but not convex?

Comment: Is an example $S=\{1,5\}$?

Comment: Sure, that's an example.